# ListActivity not working

Tags: android

I'm creating a menu where all of my activity will be on the list, and whenever i clicked an activity from that list, it should start that activity.

here is my menu.java

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity
{
    String classnames[] = {"MainActivity","example1","example2","example3",
    "example4","example5","example6","example7","example8","example9","example10"};
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classnames));
    }
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String classClicked = classnames[position];
        try
        {
            Class ourclass = Class.forName("android.intent.action."+classClicked);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourclass);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

here is my manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

It don't have any error but my MainActivity doesn't start even when I clicked it.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getListView().setOnItemClickListener` instead of `onListItemClick`. Why? to be honest i also dont know, but it solved my problem.

Comment: Can you give me a sample code? I have no idea how to use that. thanks

Comment: @monkeycoder just override  `getListView().setOnItemClickListener` like you did when you set a `button`'s `onClickListener`. I believe you can googling/do it your self :)

Answer (score 1):

You must declare all your activities in `AndroidManifest.xml` otherwise it won't work. Your updated manifest file should look like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example3"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example4"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example5"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example6"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example7"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example8"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example9"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".example10"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Menu.java

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity
{
String classnames[] = {"MainActivity","example1","example2","example3",
"example4","example5","example6","example7","example8","example9","example10"};
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classnames));

getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {

            String classClicked = classnames[position];

            try {
                    Class ourclass = Class.forName("android.intent.action."+classClicked);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ourclass);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    });
}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    /*super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String classClicked = classnames[position];
    try
    {
        Class ourclass = Class.forName("android.intent.action."+classClicked);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourclass);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}

}
```

And now everything should work.

Comment: those example activities is just a filler, I tried your code and it doesn't work.

Comment: @monkeycoder You could try another method, instead of using `onListItemClick` you could use `getListView()`. I have posted updated `Menu.java`, you should try and see if it works.

Comment: I can't accept this as an answer since Blaze Tama gave hint, but I'll give you an upvote. thanks bud.

Answer (score 0):

You must register the other activities in your manifest, just like the mainactivity. Otherwise Android wont start them.

Comment: No, i don't have classes for those activity. Its just a filler.